# How to set inktoolbar's pen color

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, inkcanvas

As the code shown, I add a ballpointpen, and it support 30 colors, but not enough.

I got colorSelected(Color type) using some other ways, not discuss here. 
Now I want to click ballpointPen, using my colorSelected to draw.
How? Thanks.

```
<Grid>
        <InkToolbar TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}" InitialControls="AllExceptPens" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <InkToolbarBallpointPenButton x:Name="ballpointPen" Click="xxx_Click"/>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toolButtonColorPicker" Click="ToolButton_ColorPicker">
                <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Palette.png"/>
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Content="ColorPicker"/>
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
        </InkToolbar>
        <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Margin="0,48,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
```

The code below seems not working...

```
private void xxx_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(bUserDefinedColor)
            {
                InkDrawingAttributes drawingAttributes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.CopyDefaultDrawingAttributes();
                drawingAttributes.Color = colorSelected;
                inkCanvas.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(drawingAttributes);
            }
        }
```

by the way, I upload the test project to GitHub https://github.com/hupo376787/Test.git

Comment: Your code should work. Where do you call it?

Comment: @JustinXL in the InkToolbarBallpointPenButton  click event. ie. when I click the ballpointpen button, it should use my color.

Comment: It should work. Please show the full source in your click handler.

Comment: @JustinXL  private void xxx_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(bUserDefinedColor)
            {
                InkDrawingAttributes drawingAttributes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.CopyDefaultDrawingAttributes();
                drawingAttributes.Color = colorSelected;
                inkCanvas.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(drawingAttributes);
            }
        }

Comment: bUserDefinedColor is ture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152321/discussion-between-vincent-and-justin-xl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a better solution to your problem, without the need of calling `UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes` directly.

What I would do is, whenever the user selects a new color from your `ColorPicker` and hits *OK*, add this color to the `Palette` of the `InkToolbarBallpointPenButton`, and then set the `SelectedBrushIndex` to the index of the newly created color.

In way you can completely **remove** your `xxx_Click` handler, and replace what's in `LeftClick` with the following

```
cpx.LeftClick += (ss, ee) =>
{
    bUserDefinedColor = true;
    colorSelected = cpx.pickerColor;

    ballpointPen.Palette.Add(new SolidColorBrush(colorSelected));
    ballpointPen.SelectedBrushIndex = ballpointPen.Palette.Count - 1;
};
```

This is it! You will see the selected color visual on the pen icon automatically reflects the new color, which gives a great user experience.

---

Here are two more things you might want to do to further enhance the UX.

1. Cache the added colors and manually add them back to the `Palette` at app startup so next time when the user opens the app, they are still available.
2. Instead of adding another icon to display the `ColorPicker`, try putting it inside the color popup of the `InkToolbarBallpointPenButton` so all color related things are in the same place. The control that sits inside this popup is called `InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl`. You should be able to locate its style (see path below) and add your `ColorPicker` to it.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.xxxxx.0\Generic\generic.xaml

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, good idea. Thanks, Justin. But I still wonder why UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes not working...

Comment: It won't work until you open the color popup of the ballpoint pen and this is by design. With your original code, try picking a color from your color picker, hit "OK"; click on the ballponit pen to select it; click on the ballpoint pen AGAIN to open the color popup; click anywhere to dismiss the popup; draw anything. This time, you will see your specified color show up on the canvas.